# How to get specific ranged words from raw corpus?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, corpus

```
import nltk   
import nltk.data    

nltk.corpus.brown    
y= nltk.corpus.brown.raw()  
print(y)
```

When I do `print(y)` it shows me all of the raw data in this corpus, 
but I want to get only `10,000` words from this raw corpus. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do :

```
import random
words = nltk.corpus.brown.words()
random_words = random.sample(words, 10000)
```

Comment: I dont need 10000 words from words. I need words from Raw corpus. 
you wrote words=nltk.corpus.brown.words() instead of words=nltk.corpus.brown.raw()

Comment: In `words()` you have all the words present in `raw()` in the same order. You can check that by doing : `nltk.corpus.brown.raw()[0:100]` and `nltk.corpus.brown.words()[0:10]`

Comment: Thanks, Its working great.  nltk.corpus.brown.words()[0:10]
this thing i actually wanted.